# In-place sorting of csc_matrix columns

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to be able to sort columns of a scipy sparse matrix. The scipy documentation is fairly terse, and I can't see much concerning modification of the matrix. On SO I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007463/sorting-in-sparse-matrix), but the answer given returns a `list`

The code that I want to write is

```
s = rand(4, 4, density=0.25, format='csc')

_,colSize = s.get_shape()    
for j in range(0,colSize):
   s.setcol(j, sorted(s.getcol(j), key=attrgetter('data'), reverse=True))
```

Except there is no `setcol` and `sorted` doesn't return the same type as `getcol`.

As an example of what I'd like to get, if I have in input

```
<class 'scipy.sparse.csc.csc_matrix'>
[[ 0.          0.33201655  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.81332962  0.          0.50794041]
 [ 0.          0.41478979  0.          0.        ]]
```

then the output that I want is

```
[[ 0.          0.81332962    0.          0.50794041]
 [ 0.          0.414789790.  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.332016550.  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.            0.          0.        ]]
```

(It doesn't have to be a csc matrix, I assumed that this would be better for column manipulations)

Comment: [Inserting null columns into a scipy sparse matrix in a specific order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49652985/inserting-null-columns-into-a-scipy-sparse-matrix-in-a-specific-order) explores some alternatives for reordering columns.  It's not in-place though.

Comment: In your example array, all the nonzero values are positive.  Is that the case for your actual arrays?

Comment: On further reading, you are trying to do something quite different from my recent linked answer.  But I'll leave that comment; it may give some useful ideas about sparse matrices.

Comment: @Warren The values are event counts, so they will be integers greater than or equal to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a short function that sorts the columns in descending order in-place:

```
import numpy as np


def sort_csc_cols(m):
    """
    Sort the columns of m in descending order.

    m must be a csc_matrix whose nonzero values are all positive.
    m is modified in-place.
    """
    seq = np.arange(m.shape[0])
    for k in range(m.indptr.size - 1):
        start, end = m.indptr[k:k + 2]
        m.data[start:end][::-1].sort()
        m.indices[start:end] = seq[:end - start]
```

For example, `s` is a `csc_matrix`:

```
In [47]: s
Out[47]: 
<8x12 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 19 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>

In [48]: s.A
Out[48]: 
array([[ 0,  2,  0,  0,  7,  0,  0, 48,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 82,  0,  0, 38, 67, 17,  9,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 47,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 99,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 83,  0,  0,  0,  9],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 85, 94,  0, 55, 68,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 22,  0,  0,  0, 71,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])

In [49]: sort_csc_cols(s)

In [50]: s.A
Out[50]: 
array([[ 0,  2, 82,  0,  7, 38, 99, 94,  9, 55, 71,  9],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 85, 83,  0,  0, 68,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 67, 48,  0,  0, 47,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 22, 17,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Comment: Works fine on a small example.